# AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens' rasa

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu

I am facing a problem working with rasa, i can't run or train or do anything because below error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in *run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\Scripts\rasa.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\rasa_*main**.py", line 118, in main
cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 235, in run
init_project(args, path)
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 130, in init_project
print_train_or_instructions(args, path)
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 69, in print_train_or_instructions
training_result = rasa.train(domain, config, training_files, output)
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\rasa\api.py", line 106, in train
from rasa.model_training import train_async
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\rasa\model_training.py", line 39, in 
from rasa.core.agent import Agent
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\agent.py", line 16, in 
from rasa.core.channels.channel import OutputChannel, UserMessage
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels_*init*_.py", line 26, in 
from rasa.core.channels.hangouts import HangoutsInput  # noqa: F401
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\hangouts.py", line 9, in 
from oauth2client import client
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 39, in 
from oauth2client import transport
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", line 17, in 
import httplib2
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\httplib2_*init*_.py", line 52, in 
from . import auth
File "c:\users\dell\anaconda3\envs\rasanew\lib\site-packages\httplib2\auth.py", line 20, in 
auth_param_name = token.copy().setName("auth-param-name").addParseAction(pp.downcaseTokens)
AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens'

Comment: Fixed in httplib2 0.20.2, released Nov 2.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue when trying rasa train. The problem seems to be the later version of pyparsing module no longer has that attribute. Downgrading it works for me.

run:

pip install pyparsing==2.4.2

then:

rasa train

Answer (score 3):

For me it was due to an incompatibility with my version of httplib2 (see https://github.com/PAIR-code/what-if-tool/issues/185#issuecomment-1013971242).

I just ran:

```
$ pip3 list | grep http
httplib2 (0.19.1)
$ pip3 install httplib2
Collecting httplib2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/20/511741a05f8a59dc98f5ad9962efdc4f7bc1126329234e18b13f0cb3ddc4/httplib2-0.20.2-py3-none-any.whl (96kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 5.5MB/s 
Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,!=3.0.2,!=3.0.3,<4,>=2.4.2; python_version > "3.0" (from httplib2)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/34/895006117f6fce0b4de045c87e154ee4a20c68ec0a4c9a36d900888fb6bc/pyparsing-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, httplib2
Successfully installed httplib2-0.20.2 pyparsing-3.0.6
```

And it worked.